Free CPU RAM while using tensorflow
At first I am sorry for this question - I know python well, but I have never worked with ML frameworks. In addition it's very hard to create full example of the problem, because I cannot setup GPU on my machine and modyfying the code on the production machine is very hard.
Coming to the problem, on the production machine I have CUDA and GPU setuped. I am using
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device("/GPU:0"):
  my_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath=filepath)

to load the model into the memory. As far as I know it should use GPU, but the model is stored in both, CPU and GPU RAM. I tried to use gc.collect(), I tried random things like tf.keras.backend.clear_session() and flags like TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH or CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES but nothing works - the CPU RAM is taken until the program terminates. I couldn't find any solution which makes me think that I do not understand something fundamental.
Is it normal behaviour that such loaded model stays in the CPU RAM? If not, what should I do to free this memory and leave it only in GPU?

Yes, it is normal behavior, the GPU is not an independent device, depends on the CPU, so weights also have to stay in RAM.

Without GPU it consumes about 10GB of CPU. With GPU it consumes 10GB of CPU and 5GB of GPU. What consumes that extra 5GB then?
